# Redirecting from a web view to a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, authentication

In this application im trying to have a landing page "Main activity 1" to display a login/registration website. Then only after the user have successfully logged in I want to display the second activity . I know that I can use parse to create an SQL DB but in this case I want to avoid that and use my website to handle the registration / login db ("tell me based on your experience if it is a stupid idea ").

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//move to second activity only afther login 
WebView webView;
public class webView() {
    if (webView.loadUrl("login URL")!= webView.loadUrl("login URL")){ //need help here
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return ;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // DISPALY WEBSITE FOR LOGIN
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("login URL");
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the webview listener and can trigger the new activity whenever the user is logged in, you can go through the below code.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            //Here check whether the url is after logged in
            if(url.equals("URL after user logged In")){
                //start new activity
          }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.. finish" + url);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            System.out.println("when you click on any interlink on webview that time you got url :-" + url);
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is perfect , thanks for the fast response and well commented code .

Comment: @SpaceCore it would be really inspiring if you upvote the answer.

Comment: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. Sorry but im a newbiee here .